# Access text-shadow property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to access `text-shadow` property just like we access `padding` property. Means ,

```
       div{
          padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
       }
```

so we can access its each part individually like:

```
          $('div').css("padding-left"); etc..
```

Now how i can access `horizontalShadow`, `verticalShadow`, `Blur`, `shadowColor` of a `textshadow` property individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-shadow) only defines the `text-shadow` property. It is not a shorthand property.

If you want to change part of a text-shadow rule, then you must take the existing rule and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

`text-shadow` is not a shorthand property like `padding` is, so you can't get the subvalues like that. You'll have to parse it manually.